# Divergence of $\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vector-fields, calculus

In David J. Griffiths's *Introduction to Electrodynamics,* the author gave the following problem in an exercise.

> *Sketch the vector function* 
>   $$ \vec{v} ~=~  \frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}, $$ 
>   *and compute its divergence, where* 
>   $$\hat{r}~:=~ \frac{\vec{r}}{r} , \qquad r~:=~|\vec{r}|.$$ 
>   *The answer may surprise you. Can you explain it?*

I found the divergence of this function as
      $$ 
    \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
  $$ 
Please tell me what is the surprising thing here.

Comment: convert your expression for $r$ into Cartesian coordinates, and then compute the divergence in these coordinates.  You definitely have the wrong answer.

Comment: Sorry, the numerator 'r' is a vector. I do not know how to put a hat over the 'r' here in this website. vecor v = vector r/ r^2.

Comment: Yes, but still, your answer should be half of what you've written.

Comment: Wait, r hat or r vector? R hat means that it is a unit vector, whereas r vector means that it is a full r vector. $\vec{r}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$, $\hat{r}=\frac{x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$. Mouseover the above two formula and right-click, show source to get an idea of how to make vectors in TeX.

Comment: ya, now I made it right. The denominator is the equation of the sphere , is that the surprising thing? or anything else important here?

Comment: Sorry, it is a r vector not r hat. Anyway thanks for the source info.

Comment: I doubt that that is the surprising thing, a symmetric situation usually gives a nice spherical answer. Ill think about it, got to go now.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/488220/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty sure the question is about $\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$, i.e. the electric field around a point charge. Naively the divergence is zero, but properly taking into account the singularity at the origin gives a delta-distribution.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same book, so I take it you are referring to Problem 1.16, which wants to find the divergence of $\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$.

If you look at the front of the book. There is an equation chart, following spherical coordinates, you get $\nabla\cdot\vec{v} = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}\left (r^2 v_r\right) + \text{ extra terms}$.
Since the function $\vec{v}$ here has no $v_\theta$ and $v_\phi$ terms the extra terms are zero.
Hence $\nabla\cdot\vec{v} = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}\left(r^2 \frac{1}{r^2}\right) = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}\left(1\right) = 0$.

At least this is how I interpret the surprising element of the question.

Comment: The surprising thing is the answer of zero in the context of the plot which naively has non zero divergence!

Answer (score 4):

For me another surprising thing about this question was that the divergence was not negative, seeing as the flow decreases as we move radially outwards. I found an excellent explanation of this here:

http://mathinsight.org/divergence_subtleties

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than answer

Comment: @freude The question is 'Please tell me what is the surprising thing here'. How is this not an answer to that question?

Comment: This helped me very much. Thanks for the link buddy.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to check if the divergence is finite everywhere.

Comment: But what is the physical meaning of infinite divergence?

Comment: @sree: Infinite charge density (if the vector field is the electric field).

Comment: The electron is a single point here. Countably many charge in an infinitely small point -> infinite charge density.